# HTML5 geolocation - why it reports different location in the browser than in a mobile app?

Tags: android, html, geolocation

I am a user of mapy.cz, Czech mapping portal that also happens to have an Android app. I guess that both the browser version and the mobile app obtain the current location from an API, the HTML5 API or an Android API. My current understanding is that in the end, both APIs talk to the "Google Location Service / Database", right?

Now, how comes that the mobile app reports a correct location while the web version reports a location a few kilometers away? My phone has of course GPS turned off to make those two scenarios comparable. Both the PC and my phone are connected to the same WiFi network at this moment. Shouldn't both APIs report the same location? If not, what makes them different? I'd like to understand this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Geolocation of a wifi adress i never 100% accurate, the city of an ip adress accuracy is between 50-80%, nation 98-99%, down to zip code or adress is even less, so you will get different results depending on what service you are using, and you can get different outcomes every time you use a single service, since it's not accurate, not like GPS that can track you to mm distances.

Edit: your mobile phone is probably more accurate because the service probably triangulates via mobile masts as well as IP

Comment: Yes, IP is very imprecise but wifi triangulation (which is a different thing) is actually pretty accurate for me most of the time - the current position is only meters or tens of meters off, not more. I thought that HTML5 API can use wifi triangulation database, can it not?